# asp dropdown, list items are scrolling with my div

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

When clicking on the DropDown, the list items box appears. Then when scrolling the page the items box scrolls with but I need it to stay attached to the DropDown List (it shouldn't move but the page must still scroll). There is no javascript involved in my code. I have noticed that when clicking on the arrows of the scroll the box dissapears but as soon as I use the mouse wheel to scroll the box scrolls with..

My Code:

Masterpage code

```
<div style="overflow-x:scroll; border: solid black 1px; height: 300px; width: 400px;">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" >

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

Default.aspx

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBox1" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <dx:ListEditItem Text="Item1" Value="Item1"></dx:ListEditItem>
        <dx:ListEditItem Text="Item2" Value="Item2"></dx:ListEditItem>
        <dx:ListEditItem Text="Item3" Value="Item3"></dx:ListEditItem>
    </Items>
</dx:ASPxComboBox>
```

I've already tried setting the position of the DropDown List to relative, absolute and fixed but it didnt work. I also tried this code

```
$('#ScrollingBox').scroll(function() {
   $("#YourDropdownListID").data("kendoDropDownList").close();
});
```

and the results were the same.

Comment: Please provide http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I tried creating it in JSfiddle but it doesn't have any asp controls

Comment: The HTML <select> (the equivalent of the dropdown list in asp) does work but I want to use the asp dropdown list not the html <select>. I need this for c# events, the <select> doesn't have them

Answer (score 0):

```
 style="position:absolute !Important;"
```

Comment: Whem I set the position to absolute !Important, it makes the whole dropdown Scroll with the page..

Comment: have u tried other options like relative and fixed with !Important?

Comment: No it doesnt work. Would you just look at my question again, I edited it

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1r" runat="server">
     <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBox1" runat="server">
       <Items>
          <dx:ListEditItem Text="Item1" Value="Item1"></dx:ListEditItem>
          <dx:ListEditItem Text="Item2" Value="Item2"></dx:ListEditItem>
          <dx:ListEditItem Text="Item3" Value="Item3"></dx:ListEditItem>
       </Items>
    </dx:ASPxComboBox>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Width="1000" ScrollBars="Auto" Height="400px">
        <!--Put Every thing else here-->
        <!--Specify Appropriate Height and Width for Panel For Your Screen Size-->
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```